# Keeping Mac OS X Server 10.5.x Security Up to Date

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I'm trying to patch several security holes in our Mac OS X Server 10.5.8 box. The holes are in OpenSSH, Apache, and PHP. Apple has notified me that they will NOT be patching these, as the 10.5.8 line has been EOL'ed.

What is the best way to update these components without "breaking" Apple's integration with the services? For example, we administer our websites on this box through Apple's Server Admin.

Thank you!