# Try fixing Apache or Wordpress error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, apache2

I have the following error message in the error log file of my website.
Can you explain me what it means, is there security problem?
How could I fix it?

> [Mon Feb 25 21:04:34 2013] [error] [client 173.199.116.83] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Mywebsite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192
>
> [Mon Feb 25 20:48:01 2013] [error] [client 80.118.73.90] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Mywebsite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192, referer: http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.banahan.fr%2F&ei=4r8rUfSBAYe2hQevjICABg&usg=AFQjCNHbl8fe0yvfJH0lEdTBUNw1FYw1tA&sig2=7PRr2vM5qj9DuX64oZXwwQ&bvm=bv.42768644,d.ZG4
>
> [Mon Feb 25 19:37:42 2013] [error] [client 91.207.4.186] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Mywebsite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192, referer: http://glavprofit.ru/
>
> [error] [client 217.13.55.146] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Mywebsite/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/Library/Tenon/PHP/lib/php') in /Mywebsite//wp-includes/update.php on line 144

Comment: ok! where is the code?

Comment: Maybe showing us the line 192 on your functions file....or the entire function and the error line???

Comment: Exactly what it says on the tin, you have a syntax error which in turn is screwing up your include.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log file is a listing of problems you need to fix.

So, if I were to take the first item as an example: go to the file referenced, go to line 192, and fix the code (opening and closing parentheses properly, using correct syntax, writing variables properly, etc).

Go down the list and do this for all of them, and your site will work properly.

Comment: This code comes from a clean install of Wordpress, I can't understand why I should have to correct some code in Wordpress, I shall think the code is correct, shouldn't it?

Comment: My intuition is telling me that you're not a coder. In that case, you're right, you shouldn't have to fix code that comes with a wordpress theme. Try activating another theme to see if it is just a theme-code problem. also, upgrade your wordpress to be the newest version, and make sure your hosting is using the newest version of PHP. anything after that shouldn't be your problem. (for further wordpress related help, go to the wordpress stackexchange site.)

Comment: Finaly it looks like that I have a security failure on my server... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483900/keeping-mac-os-x-server-10-5-x-security-up-to-date/15091735#15091735 I have the same system and from a wordpress forum I found that it is a hack failure

Answer (score 0):

I see these questions a lot and it's generally based on some plugin that was installed where the coder is trying to use php short open tags when it is not supported.

Edit you php.ini file and change the following:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

And set it to:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Then restart your apache and or php-fpm if your running fpm and check to see if the issue has gone away.  Short open tags are bad standard as per php documentation however a lot of developers still seem to keep using them regardless.

Comment: Thanks Will I will make this change.

Comment: Please keep in mind that if this fixes your issues... you now know the root cause... However I 100% dissallow short open tags on my servers, so if you wrote the code then fix the code to not use short open tags.  If it's something else at least post the code around that line so we can see and help more.

The short open tag fix should only be a temporary check to see if that truly is the issue.